# How do you post a snapshot of a code

Tags: discussion

I want to post a snapshot picture of my uncompleted code so someone more with more knowledge than me can aid me in its completiton.

Comment: Nobody wants to see a *"snapshot picture"* of your code - it's **text**, and should be presented as such (see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Also, this is neither a tutorial nor code-writing service; we aren't here to complete your code for you. You should spend some time in the Help Center, particularly [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe: OP only said to *aid me* ...

Comment: No you don't. You want to post the code *as text*, so it can be cut, copied, pasted, ... and, not incidentally, so it can also be *read.* Don't waste your time and our bandwidth posting pictures of text.

Comment: If your car doesn't start, would you send a picture of the car to a mechanic?

Comment: There is so much wrong here

Answer (score 14):

first, put an empty line before your code

```
then indent each line with 4 spaces
of your code for it to show up as code.
```